# Summing complex numbers

Tags: complex

Maybe it is a very stupid question but I am having trouble with summing complex numbers in *Mathematica*. I have

```
q = l1 E^(2 π I t1) + l2  E^(2 π I t2)
```

where `l1`, `l2` `t1`, and `t2` are known real numbers. I obtain an answer which is a set of four complex numbers.

I think it sums all the components one by one (Minkowski sum?), and I want just to sum two complex numbers to obtain a third one. What function should I use?

Comment: You might want to look at `ComplexExpand[]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "2[Pi]"?

Comment: @Peltio, Markdown strips backslashes, unfortunately. I've fixed it.

Comment: `q // ExpToTrig // Simplify` is equivalent to `q//ComplexExpand` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since `l1`, `l2`, `t1`, `t2` are known, you just need to plug them in:

```
q=l1 E^(2 \[Pi] I t1) + l2 E^(2 \[Pi] I t2) /. {l1->0.2, t1->0.1, l2->5, t2->-1}
```

gives 5.1618 + 0.117557 I

Answer (score 0):

```
   q1 = l1 E^(2 \[Pi] I t1) + l2 E^(2 \[Pi] I t2)

        q2 = q1 // ExpToTrig

        (Drop[q2, 2] // Factor) + Drop[q2, -2]

        (*  E^(2 I \[Pi] t1) l1 + E^(2 I \[Pi] t2) l2

        l1 Cos[2 \[Pi] t1] + l2 Cos[2 \[Pi] t2] + I l1 Sin[2 \[Pi] t1] + 
         I l2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t2]

        l1 Cos[2 \[Pi] t1] + l2 Cos[2 \[Pi] t2] + 
         I (l1 Sin[2 \[Pi] t1] + l2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t2])  *)
```

Have fun!